# How to compare one field of a table with another field in a different table using like

Tags: mysql

One named `keywords` with a keyword column. Another table `domains` with a column domain. I want to check if any of the keyword in the table `keywords` appear in domains or not?

How to go about it? I want to do the comparison using `like` operator. I tried this query

```
SELECT domain
FROM domains, keywords
WHERE keyword like concat('%',domain,'%')
```

But I always get empty set. For example I have a keyowrd `shop` and a domain named 'www.dailyshop.com'. Now shop is within the said domain. So 'www.dailyshop.com' should be shown in query result. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to swap the search columns. See [Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pattern-matching.html)

```
SELECT domain
FROM domains, keywords
WHERE domain like concat('%',keyword,'%');
```

e.g.

```
SELECT 'www.dailyshop.com' LIKE CONCAT('%','shop','%');
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 'www.dailyshop.com' LIKE CONCAT('%','shop','%') |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                               1 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: but I want to see if the keyword is contained with domain or not. The query you suggested will try to match a domain within the keyword right?

Comment: ok, thanks I gotta try this. Actually I thought I have to keep the order like that for keyword to get searched with domain

Comment: Wow, that was great. And I got a big misconception cleared. Thanks a million.

Comment: Ani ho. Olakhla :). Many greetings from me.